# What is Password Encryption bits

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, public-key-encryption, password-encryption

What is the "bits" meaning in password, for example 16 bit password or 128 bit password?
Can anyone make this clear for me please?
I tried to search on the web but did not fine good explain for this topic.

Comment: It is 128 bit key, not password probably. 1 byte is 8 bits. a 16 bit key means a key consisting of 2 bytes ("ab" for instance) and I don't think it is applicable for anything. A 128 bit key however means a 16 byte (128 / 8 = 16) key (or password) like "1234567890abcde"

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Dear @simon-faiman, if you find a comment helpful you should vote up, and if you find an answer useful (solution to your problem) you should mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generate a key for encryption, "bits" means the size of the key that should be generated. In a very simplified form, you can think of a key as a secret number. If you use 16 bits to store the key, there are `2^16 = 65536` possible numbers for the key. If you use more bits the range is larger and thus the key is better secured. Using a key that is too small allows to just try out every possible number via a brute-force attack. If you use more bits, the range the secret number is chose from can be large enough that a brute-force attack is not possible any more because it would took years (or even longer) to test all possible numbers. For email encryption via PGP for example, a key size of 2048 bits is recommended nowadays (may people use even 4096 bit keys).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Such a large key size is only required for asymmetric keys. For symmetric keys (as used in AES), 128 bits is enough.